# FullScreen snapshot including Statusbar?

Tags: android

I have tried to capture screen of my application,

```
public void takeSnap(View v) {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    decorView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
    decorView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    decorView.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap img = decorView.getDrawingCache();

    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.snap)).setImageBitmap(img);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            decorView.destroyDrawingCache();
            decorView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        }
    }, 400);
}
```

The problem I am facing here, it takes snapshot but no status bar icon are visible! I want statusbar icon also

[image: after taking snapshot]

Comment: you need to have root access else you cant include the status bar.

Comment: statusbar include in decorView or not? there must be some way arround

Answer (score 0):

I think its basically the permission issue. Android uses what is called a ***framebuffer*** for the video display.

The permissions on the **framebuffer** file is `rw- rw- ---` . Note that the last "group" has 3 "-"'s. That basically means that if you are not the owner (which is root) you do not have permission to even read from that file.

The apps that take the complete screenshot of the device mostly comes as a system app.For all other external apps we need a rooted phone so as to grab the complete screen.

Check in the answers in the following link : [Why do we need a rooted phone for taking screenshots](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10930/why-do-we-need-a-rooted-phone-to-capture-screenshots)

Comment: so any other solution ? for non-rooted device

Comment: As far as I know I think the answer is NO.

Comment: anytime. btw if you find any solution or alternative please do post the answer in here. :)